# channelWritabilityChanged can lead to incomplete chunk transfer by ChunkedWriteHandler

Tags: netty

io.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler#doFlush sends chunks of data using ChunkedInput. However, if ChunkedInput encapsulates a slow stream, then data will be transferred in chunks. As I understand channel writeablity can change in between chunk transfer. In such a case, will it it lead to incomplete ChunkedInput stream transfer as that ChunkedInput has been removed from io.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler#queue ? Or am I missing something here?

Thanks,
Prateek

Answer (score 0):

It should not... If it does please open a bug-report with a reproducer.

Comment: I am new to java nio, so please bear with me. if the write channel is full and it can take no more data, then channel write ability will change is my understanding leading to the scenario I mentioned above. Please correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: We will continue to write the currentWrite when the channel becomes writable again. So as stated there should be no problem.